# Vuejs add item from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code:

```
<comment-form @created="add"></comment-form>

<div v-for="(comment, index) in items" :key="comment.id">
   <comment :data="comment"></comment>
</div>
```

In mixin I have method, when event is `created` I processing this method:

```
methods: { 
  add(item) {
     this.items.push(item);
     this.$emit('added');
  }
}
```

When I add new comment, this comment appears below. How I can reverse and when adding new comment, show it in up of all comments?

I tryied:

```
v-for="(comment, index) in items.slice().reverse()"
```

But not working, comments go top down anyway.

Comment: Your code in the post seems fine, so I presume the problem is elsewhere. Can you reveal more? You might want to do the copying and reversing in a computed property, though.

Comment: @SamiHult when I add comment on page, it adds normally, when I again add comment, my new comment not show on top, it show on bottom, after old comment. How I can reverse this? And do new comment on up showing, before old comment.

Comment: There are two alternatives: you either do as you suggested and show the items in reverse order, or add new items to the top of the list: `this.items.unshift(item);`. Why your example code doesn't work as expected cannot be said without you showing more code.

Comment: @SamiHult `unshift` working!!! Thanks very much!

Comment: @SamiHult should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated code:

```
methods: { 
  add(item) {
     this.items. unshift(item);
     this.$emit('added');
  }
}
```

Basically `push()` will add element at the end of an `array`

`unshift()` will add element at the front (at the 0th index) position.

`splice('insertAtIndex', 0, 'stringToBeInserted')` will used to add element at specific index of an array.